# SSRS change background to red based on a value otherwise revert to alternate row colours

Tags: reporting-services

I have alternate colours in my report but in one field I need to change the background to red if the value is 'Y' otherwise continue with the alternate row colour. Can anyone suggest how to do this please. This is what  I tried:

```
 IIF (Fields!HasAlert.Value = "Y", "Red", IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "WHITE", "#d8dcf4"))
```

and switch but neither work.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget the `=` to start your expression with.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the color only in the specific column. Click on the column in your tablix where you need your color, then under properties -> fill -> background color. Click on the drop down and select *Expression*. Then enter your code. For example:

```
=IIF(Fields!OrderNumber.Value = 1234, "Red", "Blue")
```

If you need the color on the whole row. Select the whole detail row of your tablix, then repeat the steps from before.